# Prove that $S^{1}$ unknots in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

Tags: differential-geometry, knot-theory

The definition is, X unknots in Y if any two embeddings are equivalent.
How do you show $S^{1}$ unknots in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and in general, $S^{n}$ unknots or knots in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$?

The solution given is： The cone C(S1) in S1 in in general position is non-singular, hence we can perform a sequence of cellular moves across triangles to move s1 to the boundary of a triangle. It's easy to see that any two linear embeddings of triangles are equivalent.

Can someone explain the solution?

Comment: Intuitively, I would suggest embedding your knot in $\mathbb R^3$, then introducing a parameter that runs along the knot to obtain $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Does the solution added make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, I think so...